# Angular Reactive Form Submission Event

Tags: javascript, angular, form-submit, angular-reactive-forms

I've built a validation component that works great. However, I'd like to extend it by adding success messages when a form is submitted successfully.

In the component I pass in the form, watch for changes, and act on the error:

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(data => {
    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
        this.validation = { message: `Check for errors in the form`, valid: false };
    } else {
        this.validation = { message: '', valid: true };
    }
});
```

However I can't see a direct way to get a submission event into my component so that I can show success in the ui.

1. Can I use the [(ngSubmit)](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#saving-form-data) [event](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#onsubmit) somehow?
2. what would you do to get it?

UPDATE:

1. After significant time invested into this my [feature request is here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28743)
2. Wrote about ["success handling" on Medium](https://medium.com/@BenRacicot/success-handling-is-everyones-responsibility-40d844e6cc42)
3. (2022) we finally have the `ng-submitted` class (v12.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Angular `12.1` an `ng-submitted` class is added to the `form` element that has been submitted.

The class is automatically added on submissions, and removed on resets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any submission event directly from the FormGroup class, what I know is that you should listen it from the form template.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <!-- Your controls here-->
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your component code you should listen the submit event creating the submit() method

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sergio. What is the best way to access that event in my new component? I suppose I could add another input and update it manually but it seems that I should have access to it since I'm subscribed to the form object.